# SQL script formatting

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table such as this.  USERID, FNAME, LNAME, DOB. I want to write a script so I can output the data in a very special way. I want it to look like this:

ex.

```
UserID | FName
1      | Bob
2      | John
3      | Matt


USERID | lname
1    | Bobski
2    | Johnski
3    | Mattski


USERID | DOB
1      |june 1
2      | june2
3      | june 3
```

I need the sciplet to display it like this, this includes getting the userid and field name to display the column.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for, the following should work.  It allows you to determine what field you want returned (along with USER_ID) based off of what you pass into @colName.  Just place the desired field name in the quotes (at variable declaration).

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max),
    @colName sysname = ''

set @SQL = 'SELECT USER_ID, @colName
        FROM TABLE'

set @SQL = replace(@SQL,'@colName',@colName)

exec(@SQL)
```

UPDATE:  Now that I know what you're looking for, try the following.  There might be a better way, but this cursors through all the fields on the table (except for USER_ID) and runs a select for each.  I should note that I'm not sure if this is syntactically correct for PL/SQL (just noticed that's what you're asking about).

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max),
    @colName sysname

declare colCursor cursor for

select c.name
from sys.columns c with(nolock)
join sys.tables t with(nolock)
    on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = 'TABLE'

except

select 'USER_ID'

open colCursor
fetch next from colCursor into @colName
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

begin

set @SQL = 'SELECT USER_ID, @colName
            FROM TABLE'

set @SQL = replace(@SQL,'@colName',@colName)

exec(@SQL)

fetch next from colCursor into @colName

end

close colCursor
deallocate colCursor
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you mean @colName sysname = 'fname' for example? I tried this and I got an error. As well I want it to return all fields (fname, lname, dob), not a specific field.

Comment: Weird, I don't get an error when I run it in my environment.  Regardless, it's obviously not what you need.  Are the 4 fields you have listed in your question the only fields you're concerned about?

Comment: No, I am using a simple example, my actual tables have over 20 fields (I also have multiple different tables i want to use the same concept on).

Comment: I keep receiving an error about the @SQL ( Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:)

Comment: Yeah, must be a syntax thing since you're running PL/SQL.